# Allow access to private files only to Drupal, rest all 'access denied'

Tags: files, .htaccess

I have a drupal 7 installation with [PDF module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf) on NGINX server. I have a PDF.js field configured in all of the content types, PDF uploads through this goes to private (I NEED this as private). pdf.js viewer shows a 403 when upload path is set to private. But works fine when upload path is changed to public.
I tried modifying .htaccess (my drupal is currently on localhost, also accessible through an IP):

`Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost 
Satisfy Any`

Also,

`Order Allow, Deny
Deny from all
Allow from localhost`

Also tried IP address in place of localhost, still nothing. I want pdf.js viewer to display private pdf files, but the pdf files should be inaccessible through their direct URL to both anonymous as well as authenticated users.

Comment: `nginx` does not use `.htaccess` files - those are only relevant to Apache web server.

Comment: @Richard, I just found winginx.com which converts htaccess rules to nginx configuration. So am i doing the correct htaccess?